# How do I make a button-like filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to make a button-like filter in my web. Right now, I just put the radio-button filter inside the box, but I want to remove the radio button and just make the filter work when I just click the box.

The code looks like this right now:

```
                        <div class="question-header" data-bind="visible: jobQuestions().length > 0">
                            <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-1">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <input type="radio" value="new" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" class="" />
                                    New Questions
                                    (<span data-bind="text: newJobQuestionsCount"></span>)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-2">
                                <div class="panel-body"">
                                    <input type="radio" value="ignored" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" />
                                    Ignored Questions
                                    (<span data-bind="text: ignoredJobQuestionsCount"></span>)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-3">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <input type="radio" value="answered" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" />
                                    Answered Questions
                                    (<span data-bind="text: answeredJobQuestionsCount"></span>)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-4">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <input type="radio" value="all" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" />
                                    All Questions
                                    (<span data-bind="text: allJobQuestionsCount"></span>)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

What do i have to fix?

EDIT:
[image]

When I try to hover it, the bg-color of the entire box changes, but when I just click it only the part of it changes. I am assuming this is because the label size is not full. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding an `id` to each of the radio buttons and then wrapping the `.panel-body` in a `label` like this:

```
<label for="radio1">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="radio" value="new" id="radio1" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" class="" />
        New Questions
        (<span data-bind="text: newJobQuestionsCount"></span>)
    </div>
</label>
```

Then in your css apply `display: none` to all the radio buttons you want to hide.

**EDIT**

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/OmqGpo?editors=1100) that will give you the desired results. The only thing you will need to do is arrange the buttons horizontally like the image you provided. I hope this gets you on the right track.

Play around with that for a while to familiarize yourself with how it works.

Comment: Thank you sir! It works. By the way, how can I make the background color of the box change after I click it and change back to white if i click a different box?

Comment: yes that is due to the label not filling the space of the panel-body. Your panel-body class may have some padding on it causing this issue. Not sure though since you don't have an example I can look at.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `input` an `id`, use a `label` with the `for` attribute to connect the `label` to the `input`, hide the `input`, and use the `:checked` pseudo class and adjacent sibling selector to style the `label` when an input is selected by clicking on the `label`.

And since you want to only be able to select one input at a time, you need to give the elements a `name` attribute so they're all tied to providing a value for that `name`

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #09c;
}
label {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="question-header" data-bind="visible: jobQuestions().length > 0">
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-1">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="radio" value="new" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" class="" id="new" name="someName" /> <label for="new">New Questions (
      <span data-bind="text: newJobQuestionsCount"></span>)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-2">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="radio" value="ignored" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" id="ignored" name="someName"/><label for="ignored"> Ignored Questions (
      <span data-bind="text: ignoredJobQuestionsCount"></span>)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-3">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="radio" value="answered" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" id="answered" name="someName"/><label for="answered"> Answered Questions (
      <span data-bind="text: answeredJobQuestionsCount"></span>)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="filter-4">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="radio" value="all" name="someName" data-bind="checked: jobQuestionsFilter" id="all"/> <label for="all">All Questions (
      <span data-bind="text: allJobQuestionsCount"></span>)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it is not present in the OP's example but in your example you cannot deselect any of the options once clicked. OP: If you want this to work properly you will also need to add a `name` tag to all of the inputs with the same name. This will make it so only 1 option can be checked.

Comment: @Matthew yeah, no idea what their form does and if that's by design or not, so I just left it alone.

Comment: @Matthew few more issues that I want to fix with your suggestion above. The radio button is gone but it doesnt work when I try to click the outer side of the box. How can I make the effective range broader?

Also, how can i make the background color remain after i click it and change back to white after i click a different button? Thanks

Comment: @user7677413 did you mean to comment on the other person's answer? To increase the area you can click on, use padding or increase the height/width of the label. Updated my answer with an example. I already updated the answer with how you get it to change back to white after selecting another label *"And since you want to only be able to select one input at a time, you need to give the elements a name attribute so they're all tied to providing a value for that name"*

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks it works! One thing that I want to modify though is, how can I make the entire box (col-sm-3) that is wrapping the label change its bg-color?

Comment: @user7677413 like mentioned, "... increase the height/width of the label." Add `height: 100%; width: 100%;` - updated my answer.